# Выравнивание текста внутри кнопки по центру

Tags: android, button

Использую следующий код для задания стиля кнопки и текста

```
<style name="ButtonText">
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">34dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
<item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
<item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

кнопки описываются все вот так

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/ButtonStop" />
```

По идее текст в кнопках должен быть ровно по центру, но он смещен вниз и меня это крайне не устраивает. Что я делаю не так?

бэкграунд кнопок на всякий случай

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#70c656" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#53933f" />
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#70c656"
            android:endColor="#53933f"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#53933f" />
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

И скрин с проблемой

[image]

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте указать в качестве `android:layout_height` значение `wrap_content`.

Comment: с android:layout_heigh все ОК. Проблема решилаcь убираением паддингов со шрифтов:
<item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>